# setState() called after dispose() using showDatePicker

Tags: datetime, dart, flutter, dispose, setstate

I am trying to change the date value to the picked one in the showDatePicker but whenever it is called and I pick the date it gives me the error that setState() is called after dispose(), this setup used to work fine for me not sure what changed the error. I even added if(this.mounted) to the setState but now it never gets called because mounted becomes false before that, not sure how to setState before dispose.

```
      DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();
      final f = new DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US");
      String date;
      Future<Null> _buildShowDate(
      BuildContext context, Function addProductOrder) async {
        final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                   initialDate: _date,
                                  firstDate: new DateTime(
                                                DateTime.now().year, 
                                                   DateTime.now().month,
                                                    DateTime.now().day),
                                  lastDate: new DateTime(2020));
     print(this.mounted);
     if (this.mounted) {
       if (picked != null && picked != _date) {
         setState(() {
           _date = picked;
           date = f.format(_date);
         });
  }
}
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @temirbek i did solve it awhile ago not sure what the problem was, if you share the code i could look through it and see if i notice the problem